# Mysql: slave read binlog from local storage

Tags: mysql, replication

I am running master-slave replication, Can I manually move binlog files from the master server to the slave and make the slave read them locally?

I am willing to do so because I am running out of space on the master storage. and the number of binlog files is huge.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all binary logs from the master. Just the ones that your slave hasn't read yet.

On your slave you can do `show slave status\G`. Look for the lines `Master_Log_File` and      `Relay_Master_Log_File`. The first is the binary log file, that your master is using, the second is the log file that your slave is currently reading.

You can then delete all binary logs on the master, that the slave has already read.
For example, Relay_Master_Log_File is mysql-bin.011096, then you could execute the following statement on the master:

```
purge binary logs to 'mysql-bin.011096';
```

This is described in more detail [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/purge-binary-logs.html).

You can also configure your master to hold less binary logs by configuring the `expire_logs_days` variable. Read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days).

I assume this already solves your storage problems.

**UPDATE** based on comment: You can simply copy the binary logs to the slave. Remember the position you already have from the `show slave status` output. Stop the slave. Then execute the binary logs on the slave with

```
# mysqlbinlog binlog-file1 binlog-file2 --start-position=x | mysql
```

Note that the `--start-position` parameter is only applied to the first binlog file you specify as parameter. Make sure to specify the right one.

Then read the last position from the last binary log with

```
# mysqlbinlog binlog-file99 | tail
```

and change the coordinates with

```
mysql> change master to master_log_file='...', ...
```

to the appropriate position and start the slave again.

Read more about this [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog.html) (I guess)

Comment: I surely know that I can delete files already read by slave, the problem is the difference between them both is huge, and the number of unread files as well. here the slave needs days to catch up the master and be on sync.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Slave purges old log files on its own.  No problem.

The Master does not have a perfect way to get rid of old binlogs.

The Master can't remove an old binlog until *all* the slaves have copied it to their relay logs.  But the Master neither has a list of Slaves, nor does it know where each is in the copying process.

`expire_logs_days` works pretty well, but if a slave is 8 days behind, yet the setting is 7, you are hosed.

I don't think the binlog and the relaylog have identical formats.  They certainly cannot be assumed to be in sync -- That is, the first item in a relay log does not necessarily match the first entry in some binlog.